# Zabbix dashboard error after a successful login in dashboard

Tags: zabbix, selinux

I have successfully installed and configuration part of the zabbix installation on rHEL 6.x.

After login into a dashboard, zabbix server is showing offline with following error message:

**Zabbix server is not running: the information displayed may not be current**

I have tried many things like SELinux parameter modification, rebooting server, reconfigure of zabbix configuration file with localhost and server IP Address. But, still the error remains as it is.

Please any one help to resolve it. I need to get a solution as early possible.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Get into the `zabbix.conf.php`

```
 >$sudo vim /etc/zabbix/web/zabbix.conf.php
   >$ZBX_SERVER      = '**your zabbix ip address or DNS name**';
   >$ZBX_SERVER_PORT = '10051';
   >$ZBX_SERVER_NAME = '**your zabbix hostname**';
```

Just change the ip address you can resolve the error :

> Zabbix server is not running: the information displayed may not be
>   current

After that restart the zabbix server

> $sudo service zabbix-server restart
>   To verify go to Dashboard Administration -> queue there you see data

I resolved my error like this works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

In `conf/zabbix.conf.php` file, there are the following lines:

```
$ZBX_SERVER      = 'localhost';
$ZBX_SERVER_PORT = '10051';
```

The frontend checks whether Zabbix server is running by trying to connect to the specified host and port. So whatever prevents the frontend from connecting to the server, you should find a way to allow it. (Note also that in order for the frontend to connect to the server, the latter should have at least one trapper running.)

Comment: Hi,

I have checked with following options but it has still not resolved the problem:

-> SELinux in permissive Mode
-> SELinux in enforcing Mode
-> Checked with localhost and server IP Address in configuration of zabbix
-> Checked with port allow in server
-> Checked with required function open in PHP settings like fsockopen(), mysql.sockbut still it is not resolved.

Thanks,

Comment: Could you please describe what exactly was the problem? For me, it is not obvious how SQL file import could have caused this, so your explanation might be beneficial for those whose encounter this issue later on.

Comment: I have upgraded/installed Zabbix with the latest version files and import database files schema, images and data again which has fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

First step，you should check if the zabbix server daemon is running.

if running: check the zabbix configuration,like above. Otherwise, you should find the reason why zabbix server daemon is not running and solve it.

I think the problem is probably that you missed some libraries when you installed zabbix server.

Answer (score 0):

If your zabbix-server is separate from your gui server (i.e. it is not localhost), there is a configuration setting (literally at the very end of the configuration file on the zabbix-server in 6.0) /etc/zabbix/zabbix_server.conf

```
## Option: NodeAddress
...
#
# Mandatory: no
# Default:
# NodeAddress=localhost:10051
```

This is what the web front end uses to try and connect to the main server for system information.  Set this value for your zabbix-server's ip:10051, systemctl restart zabbix-server and then your front end will no longer display the error and your system information will return.